# Get loop text values from mform

Tags: moodle

Mmform has a 'count' textfield. When user has filled with value 3, mform should create 'Unit part' by looping the textfields
(forename, designation and filemanager). Upon mform submission, I need to display Unit part filled by the user.
Could you let me know suggestions.

```
<?php     
require('config.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/formslib.php');

class active_form extends moodleform {

    function definition()   {
            
        $mform = $this->_form;      
        $fileoptions = $this->_customdata['fileoptions'];
    
        $count = $mform->addElement('text', 'count', get_string('count', 'form'), array('name' => 'count[]');
        $count = $mform->setType('count', PARAM_INT);

        for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {

            // Unit
            $mform->addElement('text', 'forename', get_string('forename', 'form'), array('name'=>'forename[]'));                        
            $mform->setType('forename', PARAM_RAW);

            $mform->addElement('text', 'designation', get_string('designation', 'form'), array('name'=>'designation[]'));                       
            $mform->setType('designation', PARAM_RAW);          

            $mform->addElement('filemanager', 'attachment', get_string('attachment', 'form'), null, $fileoptions);                         
            $mform->setType('attachment', PARAM_RAW);
        }       
       $this->add_action_buttons();     
    }

    function validation($data, $files) {
        $errors = parent::validation($data, $files);
        return $errors;
    }
}

$mform = new active_form(null, $customdata);

if ($mform->is_submitted()) { 

    $data = $mform->get_data();
    for ($i=1; $i <= $data->count; $i++) { 
        $forename = $data->forename;
        $designation = $data->designation;
        $attachment = $data->attachment;

        echo 'forename' . $forename. '<br>';
        echo 'designation' . $designation. '<br>';
        echo 'attachment' . $attachment. '<br>';    
    }       
} 

echo $OUTPUT->header();

$mform->display();

echo $OUTPUT->footer();

?>
```

ex: User has filled with

```
count: 3

forename = SVs Group
designation = Assistant Engineer
attachment = 676208496

forename = Prime Group
designation = Staff Member
attachment = 646759033

forename = Ecos Group
designation = Staff Member
attachment = 107025147
```

**Output:**

```
count:3

forename: SVs Group
designation: Assistant Engineer
attachment: 676208496

forename: Prime Group
designation: Staff Member
attachment: 646759033

forename: Ecos Group
designation: Staff Member
attachment: 107025147
```

Comment: I'm not able tow write a full answer right now, but take a look at how Moodle handles repeat elements in forms: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_repeat_elements

Comment: Thank You for the link.Its good to repeat the elements. Could I know how could we get the text values filled by the user. I'm able to repeat the text element. When I try to get_data. I was not able to get all the values, rather it shows the last element values.

Comment: In your code, you've given the element the name "forename" - if you call it "forename[]" instead, then it will probably work. But, overall, you are much better using the built-in repeat elements support for handling them.

Comment: I just followed the repeated elements structure from the above link. var_dump($data); is showing perfect results, where I want to display them when form is submitted. Is this the right way of getting the values: if ($mform->is_submitted()) { $data = $mform->get_data(); foreach ($data as $d) { echo $d->forename;} }

Comment: Normally just write: if ($data = $mform->get_data()) {, as get_data() checks is_submitted(). I can't remember the exact structure of the returned data for repeat elements, but if you have used var_dump($data) to examine it, then it should be fairly obvious how to extract the values you want (or hunt through core Moodle code for examples that already use repeat elements and see what they do.